pip fails because it could not find a version of setuptools but it's installed?
I am trying to install a package with pip on a system where internet connectivity is not possible. I have all the files (wheel and tar.gz) for the necessary packages on the local hard drive.
When I try to install a package I get this:
(...)> pip install --no-index -f . --no-cache-dir curio
Looking in links: .
Processing c:\users\gabe2\projects\corrosion\dist\send\curio-1.6.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      Looking in links: .
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

It seems like the cause of the error is this:
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0

But it's a lie, because setuptools 65.5.0 is installed.
(...)> pip list
Package       Version
------------- --------------
async-helpers 1.0
hanna-meter   2024.5.19.dev3
pip           23.2.1
setuptools    65.5.0

What is going on?
P.S. All of the required files are present
(...)> ls
async_helpers-1.0-py3-none-any.whl*  hanna_meter-2024.5.19.dev3-py3-none-any.whl*
curio-1.6.tar.gz*                    venv/


You can find an answer here

There's a fantastic answer for this issue here. From the steps you've provided, it might be possible that the OS or Python version of the device on which you collected your .whl files might be different from the one you are hoping to install it on. The absence of a requirements.txt might also have caused pip to become confused when finding the correct version of the packages.
I tried their process installing matplotlib offline in a new environment, and it went smoothly, so it might work for you as well. To sum it up step-by-step:

Start from a device with internet access which has the same OS as the one you want to install things offline on. On it, create a Python environment with the same Python version as the offline PC's one.

conda create -n name-of-your-env python==3.x.x


In that new environment, install the package(s) you want using pip. In my case, it was matplotlib, so I ran the following:

pip install matplotlib


Once you have done so, create a directory in which to store all the files you'll subsequently use for the installation.

mkdir "Path/to/folder"


Then, generate and save a requirements.txt file to that folder using pip:

pip freeze > "Path/to/folder/requirements.txt"


With that requirements file, you can then download the correct libraries and their dependencies to the folder you created earlier:

pip download -r "Path/to/folder/requirements.txt" -d "Path/to/folder"


With that done, zip the folder (if needed) and transfer it over to the offline device.
You can then use pip to install the packages offline using the following:

pip install -r "Path/to/folder/requirements.txt" --no-index --find-links matplotlib

If the pip version on your offline device significantly outdated, you might need to start off with updating pip, but this method should hopefully work for you after that.

This is a great answer, and will probably help others looking for this. But in my case the answer turned out to be much simpler

Thanks for the upvote! I appreciate it. Out of curiosity, what went wrong with your installation, and how did you end up fixing it, since you say the solution was quite simple?

I figured it out, turns out that just having all of the install_requires dependencies isn't enough. You also need to have all of the build dependencies (and their transitive dependencies) present on the local hard drive to, in order to install a package with --no-index. In my case that meant setuptools and wheel.
You need to have these even though they are already installed. I'm not sure why that is, but I took a guess based on the way that the build package (which I use to create wheels for deployment) creates a completely fresh environment, and guessed that maybe pip was doing something similar for this third-party dependency. And it worked!

"You need to have these even though they are already installed. I'm not sure why…: This is because pip has very strong "PyPI first!" attitude. When pip sees a dependency it doesn't check if it's already installed. 1st it checks what version is available in indices (with --no-index it checks the directory pointed to by --find-links). If it finds some version then it compares with what is installed and upgrades if needed. If it doesn't find any version it reports error still without checking what is installed. To be continued…

…Continue. Some package declared a dependency setuptools>=40.8.0 so pip 1st wants to check that in index or --find-links.
